How do you use the Gelfond-Schneider Theorem to prove that $3^i$ is transcendental?
I'm doing a close study of David Nelson's Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics (4th ed.).
Under the entry Gelfond-Schneider theorem it says:

For example, $2^{\sqrt 2}$ and $3^i$ are transcendental.

Recall the statement of the Gelfond-Schneider theorem:

if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers such that $a \ne 0$ or $1$, and $b$ is not rational, then $a^b$ is a transcendental number.

Now it's trivially clear how the Gelfond-Schneider theorem gives that $2^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental.
However, is it not the case that $i$ is (technically) rational? After all, it's Gaussian rational.
Expanding $3^i$ you get:
$$3^i = e^{i \ln 3}$$
which expands to:
$$3^i = \cos (\ln 3) + i \sin (\ln 3)$$
which does not actually get us any closer to an insight on the transcental nature (or not) of $3^i$.
So my question is: if $a$ is algebraic and $b$ algebraic but is imaginary or complex, does it then also follow automatically that $b$ is in this context considered "not rational", making it such that $a^b$ is indeed transcendental?

"Rational" means rational in the usual sense, quotient of two integers.  $i$ isn't rational.

@lulu Thank you, yes I believe this question could go into the category of "brainfart". I really should have looked a bit more closely.

$i$ is not rational. $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb R$.
